# jQuery: change slideUp to fadeOut

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, fadein, fadeout

I have function to DropDown menu with `SlideToggle()` and I want to change it to `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` (or `fadeToggle()` I dont know...).

```
Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function (e) {
            var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
                $next = $this.next();

            $next.fadeIn(1000);
            $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

            if (!e.data.multiple) {
                $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
            }
            ;
        }
```

I change `$next.slideToggle();` to `$next.fadeIn(1000);` and it appears very well but I dont know how to hide it with `fadeOut()`.

I tried here:  `$el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');`
and changed in many ways but something is still not working.

Someone know how should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function (e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
    $this = $(this),
    $next = $this.next();

    $next.fadeIn(1000);

    //What do you do this for?
    //$this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
        $this.fadeOut(1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind I find solution :D

Changed `$next.fadeIn(1000);` to `$next.fadeToggle(1000);`